# How to design a template for printing variable data on a label

Tags: batch-processing, print-production

I designed a product label in Inkscape, saved as PNG. The manufacturer of the product needs to print batch number, best before etc using his own printer at the manufacturing site which uses CDR file format.  How do I create a template for the manufacturers printer?

I need to know how to create a template where just the space for batch number  is editable, so the manufacturer can input the required data.

Should I create another layer, bring batch no. & space for inputting data to that layer and delete all other layers in the label? Then save as SVG? The manufacturer will then type text in that space?

Comment: It's unclear what are you asking for. How to design a template for code machine or how to save cdr from inkscape.

Comment: PNG isn't generally used for print, it's a web format, so I wouldn't recommend that. Better to output as SVG - then you can probably import it right in CorelDraw. Isn't the label already the template? Surely there's a gap or space left for the date?  Inkscape can't save CDR files, it's native format is SVG. Perhaps some other format might work better, such as PDF?

Comment: hi @SZCZERZOKŁY  thanks for reply. I need to know how to create a template, where just the space for batch number etc is editable, so the manufacturer can input the required data.   Is this what I should do. create another layer, bring  batch no. & space for inputting data. to that layer and delete all other layers in the label? then save as svg. The manufacturer will then type text in that space? Apologies if I sound a little scrambled, I usually design textiles, Creating labels is a first for me. And thanks once again for your advice and replies, it is genuinely appreciated.

Comment: Thanks @BillyKerr yes I can output as svg. but pdf is not editable. so how would the manufacturer input data

Comment: OK I'm going to answer now.

Answer (score 2):

You could type some dummy text to act like a  placeholder, then the manufacturer could just select it, and type their own text.  This could be done if the SVG contains editable text. You could lock other elements so they aren't editable - but that would probably only work in Inkscape.

If a CDR file is what's required, then it would probably be better to use CorelDraw to set it up.  Inkscape can't generate a CDR file, it's native file format is SVG.  I don't know how well CorelDraw supports the SVG format or if editable text in an Inkscape SVG would be still editable when imported in CorelDraw. I suppose you could try it and see, or perhaps a CorelDraw user could answer that?

Another option might be to import the SVG into DTP software such as InDesign, or Scribus even, and then add an editable text placeholder. Or perhaps the manufacturer could just use Inkscape - since it's free, and it works on Macs, Windows, and Linux.

Comment: The easiest would be for the manufacturer to get inkscape.  However, he is not very computer savvy.  He says if it involves anything more than having to type numbers, he can't do it.  I think I will try the layer method and test it as an svg file in coreldraw and see if it works and mainly that the dimensions do not change.  Thanks for your help @billyKerr

Comment: @Mimi Well if they are capable of typing text in CorelDraw, then typing text in Inkscape is not really any more difficult.

Answer (score 1):

Code machines or jet printers have data generators build in. So all those "best before, batch numbers" and so on are usually not needed to be delivered.

Templates usually just require to mark spot where the data need to go on final label. 
So you printer template should just be shape of it with place for data marked with spot where the data should go.

So for example your label look like this [image: label]

The template should be just rectangle, with it border marked with spot color. And the place for barcode (let's call it code place) should be filled with spot color. Once the template is loaded to machine it will recognise the place and position final product in such way that printing head will be facing empty space.

Now, different thing is when the machine is label printing. Like this 
[image: label printers]

Then files should be delivered in two section. One is "constant" so pictures and so one, that don't change from label to label. And second one, which is loaded into printer management software where operator see only wireframe and places where all variable data can go. 
[image: Label printed with lablel printer]

This label is designed as whole in label printer software.

But as you can see the variables are dates. So for the operator place where the dates belong should be leaved blank.